# Websphere MQ channels timedout AMQ9271 error

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, ibm-mq

Recently we noticed below error in AMQERR01.log on the websphere MQ server.

```
AMQ9271: Channel 'SVRCONN1' timed out.
ACTION:
The return code from the select() [TIMEOUT] 65 seconds call was 0 (X'0').
AMQ9999: Channel 'SVRCONN1' to host 'x.x.x.x' ended abnormally.

dis channel(SVRCONN1)
     1 : dis channel(SVRCONN1)
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(SVRCONN1)                    CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   ALTDATE(2015-10-20)                     ALTTIME(13.28.54)
   COMPHDR(NONE)                           COMPMSG(NONE)
   DESCR( )                                **DISCINT(0)**
   HBINT(300)                              KAINT(AUTO)
   MAXINST(999999999)                      MAXINSTC(999999999)
   MAXMSGL(4194304)                        MCAUSER(busyuser)
   MONCHL(QMGR)                            RCVDATA( )
   RCVEXIT( )                              SCYDATA( )
   SCYEXIT( )                              SENDDATA( )
   SENDEXIT( )                             **SHARECNV(10)**
   SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)                      SSLCIPH( )
   SSLPEER( )                              TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

we did not configure any of the channel properties other than mcauser.

On the other side web server uses wmqjms.rar resource adapter on JBoss environment and creates 10 subscribers to one of a topic defined in MQ server. it communicates with the SVRCONN1 channel.

there are six MDBs on the web server are not responding to any messages that is published on the topic it subscribed to. remaining 4 are still alive and responding properly. by the way all these MDBs have same configuration - uses same QM, SVRCONN1 channel, same topic...

there are six entries of 'channel ended abnormally' (above error) is in AMQERR01.log.

** update **

Resource adapter properties

connectionConcurrency       1
maxConnections              50
reconnectionRetryCount      5
reconnectionRetryInterval   300000

what could be the reason for timeout? Is this a configuration issue?

thanks

Comment: What version of MQ are you using?  I found this info about MQ v7.1  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV14295

Comment: we use 7.5.0.4. I saw that page but not able to conclude on what parameter so I gave the channel details in the original post. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Could you please provide the Channel definition for SVRCONN1 channel.

Comment: I use the default channel definition to define this channel. DEFINE CHL(channel name) CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN). channel properties are shown above.

Comment: The SYSTEM.DEF.SENDER has no bearing on your SVRCONN channel, you may delete that information from your question.

Comment: ok. I added resource adapter properties and removed SYSTEM.DEF.SENDER

Comment: The error indicates the client did not respond in 65 seconds. please check why the client did not respond in 65 seconds and what was the HBINT set on the client side. It is also worth checking whether changing to SHARECNV(1) makes any difference. If this does not help, please open a PMR with MQ support.

Comment: I use the websphere mq resource adapter on JBoss environment. there is no errors/info in Jboss logs where the wmqjmsra.rar file is deployed. I will definitely try setting SHARECNV(1) on server channel. but HBINT is not available in ra.xml to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using IBM MQ 7.5.0.5.  That patch level includes a fix for XA transaction recovery with JBoss.

As to logging for the IBM MQ JCA in JBoss, you can configure the IBM Common Services in your standalone.xml:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status" value="OFF"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.level" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.append" value="false"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.startup" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.maxBytes" value="-1"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.limit" value="5000000"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.count" value="5"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.standalone" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.errorStream" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/wmq-trace-error.log"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/wmq-trace.log"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.outputName" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/wmq.log"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.status" value="ON"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.maxBytes" value="-1"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.limit" value="5000000"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.count" value="5"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.append" value="false"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.ffst.suppress" value="-1"/>
</system-properties>
```

Note that this configuration places the IBM MQ logs in the JBoss log directory.

Then, configure the IBM MQ JCA for logging:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="logWriterEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceLevel">
                    6
                </config-property>
```

A 'traceLevel' of 6 is INFO level logging, while 3 is WARN/ERROR.

The wmq-trace.log file may have more detailed information on your time out.

Comment: thanks @DougGrove, we enabled trace as you suggested. I noticed XATransaction tag is mentioned on ra.xml of websphere mq resource adapter but that tag is not there under resource adapter section as you gave above. **<transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>**

Comment: If you like, my full cnfiguration fo rthe IBM MQ JCA:

Answer (score 0):

If you like, my full configuration for the IBM MQ JCA:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.7.5.0.4.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.7.5.0.4.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="logWriterEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="maxConnections">
                    100
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceLevel">
                    6
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="connectionConcurrency">
                    1
                </config-property>
```

Comment: thanks again @DougGrove. May I know what value do you have for these properties in wmq rar? reconnectionRetryCount, reconnectionRetryInterval?

Comment: I actually use "reconnectionRetryCount" = 1000 and "reconnectionRetryInterval"  =  30000.  I up the count as I want the MQ JCA to retry for longer than the default.